# multiple applets in one jar file, multiple applets on one page?

Tags: java, applet

I have recently started developing applets.

I want to know if it is possible to:

1. package multiple applets in one jar file
   if yes, how do I do this ?
   if no, why not ? (i.e. technical reason)
2. use multiple applets on the same page
   if yes, how do I reference a particular applet from an archive, in my page?
   if no, why not ? (i.e. technical reason)

Are there any gotchas I need to be aware of for either of the above?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes you can package many applets in one jar. Just include all the Applet's classes.
2. Yes, you can do that by referencing a different class name each time.

Read [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/applet.html) for the details of the applet tag.