# Multiple Applets in One Jar File - Permissions

Tags: java, applet, manifest

I'm having some problems with multiple applets contained in one jar, and the manifest file of the jar. Basically, I'm adding some manifest attributes to the jars manifest using ant:

```
<target name="-pre-init">

    <echo message="Updating Manifest"/>

    <manifest file="MANIFEST.MF" mode="update">
        <attribute name="Permissions" value="all-permissions" />           
        <attribute name="Codebase" value="*" />
        <attribute name="Application-Name" value="APP_NAME"/>
    </manifest>

</target>
```

After doing this, I do some obfuscation, and sign the jar. The manifest file inside this completed jar contains the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Application-Name: APP_NAME
Class-Path: lib/plugin.jar
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: 1.7.0_45-b18 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: 
Codebase: *
```

However, when I use the applets contained in the JAR on a web page, I get the following in the console:

```
Missing Application-Name: manifest attribute for: http://some_url/APP_NAME.jar
Missing Application-Name: manifest attribute for: http://some_url/APP_NAME.jar
Missing Application-Name: manifest attribute for: http://some_url/APP_NAME.jar
Missing Application-Name: manifest attribute for: http://some_url/APP_NAME.jar
Missing Application-Name: manifest attribute for: http://some_url/APP_NAME.jar
Missing Application-Name: manifest attribute for: http://some_url/APP_NAME.jar
```

Now, I'm not sure where to look, as I clearly see the Application-Name attribute in the manifest. The browser also complains about a missing permissions attribute, but again, I clearly see this attribute in the manifest file. Anyone have any insight as to what the problem may be?

Comment: I don't have enough of these pieces set up to test, but I think it's because your don't have a defined MainClass (making multiple applets with one jar impossible): http://stackoverflow.com/a/2591548/16959

Comment: Of course this (less detailed) answer suggests that you can: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4254674/16959

Comment: Well, the application works, I can use all the applets no problem, it's just the manifest attributes don't seem to apply to all of them...